# how to display images dynamically on dynamic positions

Tags: android, image

i have rectangles and images and i want to show that images on that positions that rectangle holds in it...it is all dynamic. and i am using bitmap class to display but now i have to set positions according to that rectangle...

please help.
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much googling I finally got my result, so I thought I'd share it with others. Override onDraw() method and put this code in it:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
this.setbMap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageTile, 0, imageTile.length));

Bitmap adapt = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap);
canvas.drawBitmap(adapt, rect.left, rect.top, paint);
```